# How to loop through a mulitdimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

```
array(2) {
    ["names"]=> array(4) { 
        [0]=> string(4) "Edit" 
        [1]=> string(6) "Delete" 
        [2]=> string(8) "Activate" 
        [3]=> string(10) "Deactivate"
    } 
    ["action"]=> array(4) { 
        [0]=> string(4) "ajax" 
        [1]=> string(4) "abc" 
        [2]=> string(4) "def" 
        [3]=> string(4) "xyz" 
    } 
}
```

How do i loop through this in a single foreach loop?

Comment: Looks like PHP? Which data do you want to iterate over? What is the result you want to get?

Comment: ya..its php i want to get each and every value in this array

Comment: i want somethin like 'Edit' -> 'ajax'.

Comment: With recursive function? Which contains a  foreach .

Comment: What's the exact end result you want? You can loop over this array in an infinite numbers of ways. Are you saying each key in `names` is associated with the corresponding key in `action`? What should the result be then? A new array? Just `echo` the values?

Comment: i want to print this: 'Edit' has 'ajax', 'Delete' has 'load', 'Activate' has 'load', 'Deactivate' has 'load'.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming both arrays are of the same size and have the same keys:

```
foreach($array['names'] as $k => $name) {
    $action = $array['actions'][$k];
    // do whatever you want to do with $name and $action
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($data['names'] as $i => $val) {
   $newArr[$val] = $data['actions'][$i];
}
```

Or if you want a one liner at that

```
$newArr = array_combine($data['names'], $data['action']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way is a recursive function which can move through even three dimensions and more

```
function MoveThroughArray($arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
            MoveThroughArray($value);
        else
            // Do Something
    }
}
```